# arraystransfer to new array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a logistical puzzle I am trying to solve in python using 2 dimensional arrays (lists of lists). Given an array like the following ...

```
 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4
 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4
```

I would like to end up with the following ...

```
 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 

 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4

 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4
```

There will be new data inserted into each "in-between row at each cell. The first matrix is to be transferred into a new larger matrix (more rows, same columns). Trying work out how to iterate the first list, filling in every other row of the second list. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused, are we just adding a blank row after every row in your original matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate list of lists with your new additional data, let's call it `list2`, then you can do:

```
newData = [list1[i/2] if i%2 == 0 else list2[i/2] for i in range(len(list1)*2)]
```

Another option is to `zip` them and flatten out tuples:

```
newData = [item for sublist in zip(list1,list2) for item in sublist]
```

Comment: @adsmith yes, was editing it in while you commented :)

Comment: Is he flattening? I think he literally just wants `list(zip(list1,list2))`

Comment: @adsmith I think he wants to keep list of lists, which this should do. Otherwise, there will be a lits of tuples of lists.

Comment: The first array is built dynamically from a database. In the second array I want to place a value below (in the next row) each cell from the first array. That value will be the result of a calculation performed on the cell above it. I don't have the additional data before visiting each cell.

Comment: @GaryRidley "Given an array" - so do you have the full first matrix in your possession before you calculate the mid-rows? If so, I don't see a problem.